# Kong ingress controller: addons OR dbless yaml?

Tags: kong, kong-ingress

I am trying to test kong ingress controller on minikube. My primary objective is to use authentication and authorization plugins for my service endpoints.

[Here](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.10.x/deployment/minikube/), it asks following to be executed to deploy Kong Ingress Controller:

> kubectl create -f
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/v2.10.0/deploy/single/all-in-one-dbless.yaml

But [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/addons/kong-ingress/), it says, we need to execute:

> minikube addons enable kong

So, which one do we actually need for minikube?